# viewbox with pixel value to make d3 chart resposive is not working properly

Tags: javascript, d3.js, viewbox

I'm trying to get d3 chart more responsive. So I used `viewbox` with pixel value but It is not working check this [non responsive jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PhY85/). If I set `width`  and `height` to `100%` as shown below then It is responsive check [responsive jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gjA73/4/)

```
var svg = d3.select('.chart-container').append("svg")
        .attr("width", '100%')
        .attr("height", '100%')
        .attr('viewBox','0 0 '+Math.min(width,height) +' '+Math.min(width,height) )
```

This is not working as shown in `non responsive jsfiddle`

```
var svg = d3.select('.chart-container').append("svg")
        .attr("width", 200)
        .attr("height", 200)
        .attr('viewBox','0 0 '+Math.min(width,height) +' '+Math.min(width,height) )
```

I want to customize `width` and `height` in d3 only not in css by set `height` and `width` of `div` and I don't want to use any `jquery` functions.

Answer (score 2):

If you get rid of the height and width attr then it becomes responsive

```
 var svg = d3.select('.chart-container').append("svg")
    .attr('viewBox','0 0 '+Math.min(width,height) +' '+Math.min(width,height) )
    .attr('preserveAspectRatio','xMinYMin')
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + Math.min(width,height) / 2 + "," + Math.min(width,height) / 2 + ")");
```